# Keeping Facebook user profile picture current

Tags: facebook

When a user signup with facebook in an app, the user profile information can be stored on the client side. What should be the strategy to refresh this?

with example flow like below.

1. User sign-up with facebook from client
2. Facebook returns user profile ( on successful user accept), token
3. client stores the user profile including profile picture url
4. client uses the url to show user image in client
5. user changes profile facebook profile image and deletes old image -> client doesn't get to know about

Given that the token may be still valid, what should be the strategy for the client to make sure the user profile picture url is current ?

Comment: Just link to `https://graph.facebook.com/{userid}/picture` . No reason to store any URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To keep the user photo current, link to `https://graph.facebook.com/{userid}/picture` wherever you would be linking to the image url in the client.**

[The `/picture` edge returns an image by default](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/]

If you want to know specifically when the user has a new profile photo, periodically check the url of the most recent photo you have against the url field returned by `https://graph.facebook.com/{userid}/picture` with `redirect=false`. If the urls differ, the user has changed their photo.